# How are PrimeFaces custom components registered in their JAR, I'm not seeing @FacesComponent and taglib.xml

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-component

I have downloaded sources of PrimeFaces 3.5 for learning purposes. 
I have no idea how PrimeFaces components are registred. From tutorials and books I learned, in order to register a custom component, the component class must be annotated with `@FacesComponent`. Additionaly, the tag must be defined in `taglib.xml` file.

In PrimeFaces source code, the component classes doesn't have any annotations and I can't find a `taglib.xml` file.

How are they registred?

Answer (score 2):

They're registered in `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` and `/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml` of the PrimeFaces **library** JAR file (thus not the **source** JAR file!). Those files are autogenerated during the library JAR build process and that's why they don't appear in the source JAR file.

Note that the `<component>` registrations in `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` are equivalent to the `@FacesComponent` annotation.